# I'm getting just key not the value from AngularFire2: Realtime Database version 5 using Angular 6.0

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6, angularfire2

I'm just getting key not the value from AngularFire2. I also tried the [Peter Pham Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587495/angularfire2-realtime-database-how-to-get-key-and-value) but the issue remain same.

```
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
```

**Firebase database**:

[image]

category.service.ts:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getCategories(){

    return this.db.list('/categories').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(categories=>{
      return categories.map(a =>{
        const value = a.payload.val();
        const key = a.payload.key;
        return {key, ...value};
      })
    }));
  }
}
```

product-form.component.ts:

```
import { CategoryService } from './../../category.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;

  constructor(public categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
   }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

product-form.component.html:

```
<select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
   <option value="">- Select -</option>
   <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
    {{c.value.name}} 
   </option>
 </select>
```

Where I'm making error? Thanks

Comment: shouldn't this `{{c.value.name}}` just be `{{c.name}}` ?

Comment: @Und3rTow if I use {{c.name}} then value="undefined" and name work fine.

Comment: ok, then move `this.categories$ = ...`  into `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 3):

As recommended by [Und3rTow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3055401/und3rtow) now it's working. I have tried the following code:

**product-form.component.html**:

```
<select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**product-form.component.ts**:

```
import { CategoryService } from './../../category.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;

  constructor(public categoryService: CategoryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories$ = this.categoryService.getCategories();
  }

}
```