# Angular 6 Firebase database can't get snapshot

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6

I upload to database like this :

My Object that I want to upload :

```
      export class Data {
          $key: string;
          name: string;
          address: string;
          address2: string;
          pscode: string;
          ccode: string;
          name2: string;
          trucks: Trucks;
          trailers: Trailers;
        email: string;
        phone: string;
        city: string;
        country: string;
        }

**Upload service :** 

  getItem: Observable<Data[]>;
key: string;
  busines = {} as Data;



   createItemAuth() {
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
  this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.auth.userId}/company`).push(this.busines)
    });
}


//this not works : 

  getUploads() {
    this.getItem = this.afDatabase.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/company/`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref;
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    });
    return this.getItem;
  }
```

on `getUploads()` `this.getItem` I get :

> Type '{ $ref: Reference; $key: string; }[]' is not assignable to type
>   'Data[]'.
>       Type '{ $ref: Reference; $key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
>         Property 'name' is missing in type '{ $ref: Reference; $key: string; }'.

**Whats wrong with that ?**

Comment: Are you using rxjs 6?

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.1.0",

Comment: Look at the second answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587495/angularfire2-realtime-database-how-to-get-key-and-value

Comment: same error, problem not there maybe

Comment: now only property key is missing not name

Comment: the problem is with this.getItem = .... - if without it, snapshot works.

Comment: getItem: Observable<any[]>; need ?

Comment: Yes this should be correct. Not sure why my comment dissapeared..

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing this.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

public mydata: Observable<any>;
public myarray = any[];

firebase.database().ref('/mypath').once('value').then(function(snapshot) { return snapshot.val(); })
      .then(items => {

        var icount = 0;
        this.mydata =[];
        this.myarray = [];

        this.mydata = items;

        for (let i in this.mydata) {

         console.log(this.mydata[i].key)
         console.log(this.mydata[i].value)
         console.log(this.mydata[i].value.something)

         this.myarray[icount] = [];
         this.myarray[icount]['something'] = this.mydata[i].val.something;

         icount++;

        }

      });

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
```

Comment: Link please Angulandy2