# Firebase - how to fetch additional data for each document on collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, angularfire2

I try to get the user for each of my messages documents. We have :

```
users
    user_id => user_data
message
    msg_id => { message, user_id }
```

So I tried ( based on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46606295/1928380) ) :

```
getUserData(userId) {
  const docRef = this.afs.collection('/users').doc(userId);
  return docRef.ref.get();
}

getMsgs(topicId){
  return this.afs.collection('/topics_msgs/' + topicId + "/comments").snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const commentData = a.payload.doc.data();
      this.getUserData(commentData.user_id).then(
        user => {
          return {user: user.data(), ...commentData};
        }
      );
    });
  });
```

}

and in component :

```
this.firebaseService.getMsgs(this.id).subscribe( msgs => {
  console.log(msgs);
  this.messages = msgs;
})
```

but of course it can't work - inner map doesn't return anything outside of the promise, so the component receives a list of `undefined`.

I'm a little stuck here about how to deal with this. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Use higher order observables to transform your data into a type that suits your need. Regarding your problem (and from what I understand), you can do something like this:

```
    getUserData(userId): Observable<UserData> {
      const docRef = this.afs.collection('/users').doc(userId);
      return docRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(action => ({ ref: action.payload.ref, ...action.payload.data()}))
      );
    }

    getMsgs(topicId): Observable<CommentData[]>{
      return this.afs.collection('/topics_msgs/' + topicId + "/comments").snapshotChanges().pipe(
        mergeMap(actions => {
          const commentsDataObservableArray: Observable<CommentData>[] = actions.map(a => {
            const commentData = a.payload.doc.data();
            return this.getUserData(commentData.user_id).pipe(
              map(user => {
                return {user: user.data(), ...commentData};
              })
            );
          });
          return combineLatest(commentsDataObservableArray);
        })
      );
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up using a similar solution but with promises, I will try your solution though since it looks good.